# Unable to fetch payload.access_token value after hitting salesforce using http connector. how to extract access_token value?

Tags: salesforce, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am hitting salesforce which is giving me **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** JSON which looks like this

```
{"access_token":"00D5j0008yLhA!ARwAQBufl2Y6S1Tu3AU5zUWBCb442Nj2JqwWFOkm3AFL16CQZleLO.mnZwlDFttOMEnldbt_WqJBzhLrh1mgI1XEIvAN8sAM","instance_url":"https://cloudceitude-13a-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com","id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D5j00000LhAEAU/0055j000004TZbAAAW","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1668188564383","signature":"LQbWIODP8pqE+wD1yjgbVUBxMDI6YV1HjENZUeK/eoY="}
```

but when I am trying to access value of access_token using payload.access_token it is giving me error

[image]

I have tried by transforming into JSON using Transform connector using

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
​---
payload
```

still after I tried to access my token it shows same error

[image]

and also while debugging **map** function is not working while working on Payload in DataWeave but instead when I use MapObject It reflect this:

```
key=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%2200D5j000008yLhA%21ARwAQIN5UGZWtk8Ucu8MUNgbnHAKleeqAk2M73Afy9iRKNEKRppu4C7Drfi0hg8q5t8C.PYX7RsMMXQPsjxmpVB1Ev_pU.2p%22%2C%22instance_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcloudcertitude-13a-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fid%2F00D5j000008yLhAEAU%2F0055j000004TZbAAAW%22%2C%22token_type%22%3A%22Bearer%22%2C%22issued_at%22%3A%221668330168420%22%2C%22signature%22%3A%22kkDnnUe9pZfiqiuEjRi02az0lwpAlmwmv3cMRmF9nRU
```

Comment: Please share the HTTP Request operation and how are you setting the payload and other inputs before it. Mask confidential information if any. Use the XML representation, code and errors should be shared as text. `when I use MapObject` how did you use mapObject() exactly? `is giving me application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON` how do you know it is using that format? Share the details for other to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an educated guess that the application or the server are somehow forcing the media type of the response to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded when it really is a JSON. The request for a token should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the response should be a JSON (application/json). If the server is returning it you should check with the administrators of that server. However if the application is overriding the content type of the response you should fix it.